# Home page isn't loading...Oops, something bad happened!

Tags: support, status-completed

The Stack Overflow home page isn't loading. I'm just getting the "Oops, something bad happened. Other pages are fine, it is just the Home Page and only seems to occur when I'm logged in.

> [image]

Comment: Is it still happening? We had CPU spikes on one web server, but those have been resolved now.

Comment: @Oded yes. Still happening for me.

Comment: Works for me, just now.

Comment: @Oded Yes it's still happening for me.

Comment: It is rather amusing to watch that screen and press F5 though.

Comment: Must be the diamonds.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling My punishment for being a bad mod.

Comment: No repro here, nor from IE11 or FF, checked both http and https

Comment: @Oded It popped up for a second and then "Oops" again

Comment: OK - looks like there's another problem elsewhere. Looking

Comment: @Oded seems to be working now... you fixed it!!

Comment: Yeah - misbehaving server taken out of rotation

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We had a misbehaving server.

It is now sat in the corner, wearing a dunce hat and no longer participating in serving up pages.

Comment: Bad server, go sit in the corner and think about what you've done!!  Oh and thanks for fixing it!!

Comment: Does this mean that once you are served by a specific server you always return to the same one?

Comment: @rene - sessions are sticky, yes.

Comment: In other words, **caching.**

Comment: In correct words, not caching.

Comment: It's happening right now too, since this morning. PHP tag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php doesn't load and brings me to http://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/questions/tagged/php but this loads http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+or+seo+or+html+or+css+or+authorize.net+or+mysql+or+payment-gateway+or+payment-processing+or+prototypejs+or+merchant-account+or+credit-card+or+pci-dss+or+pci-compliance+or+silent-post+or+recurring-billing?sort=newest&pageSize=50 - wondering if I should post a new question in meta.

Comment: @Fred-ii- - I can't reproduce this.

Comment: @Oded I've posted on meta http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295649/ and I've tried on different machines; same result.