# Single tag pages won't load, but they work if more than one is used

Tags: bug, tags

Single tags don't work, but doubles do, and they have started doing this for me since this morning (approx. 9:30am EST), along with a few other people that I've asked.

Sidenote: One of those people now informed me that it works for them, but it is erratic.

These (double tags) work and load instantly:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+mysql
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+html
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+jquery

While single tags don't, and I am redirected to an "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" page.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery

Also this brings me to an error page:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?sort=newest&pageSize=50

Here is the URL that redirects when using the PHP tag:

- https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/questions/tagged/php

It loaded fine a "few" times, out of many. But, more often not.

Stack says:

- It’s not strictly necessary, but if you’d like to give us additional information about this error, do so at our feedback site, http://meta.stackoverflow.com

This has been going on since this morning, and I have not seen anything posted on meta or in Stack Status about it, which is why I posted this.

Would this be regions-related? Or, a bad/misbehaving server?

Such as this question asked [Home page isn't loading...Oops, something bad happened!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277542/) where an answer stated so, for a similar issue.

I would also like to note that I have tried it on different machines; same result.

- I live in Canada, if that helps anyone.

---

As of approximately 7:30 PM, EST this evening, things seem to have come back to normal and all single tag pages load well and on both PCs.

Cause: Still unknown.

Second update:

It's acting up again. Started at around 8:45 PM EST, up to now being 9:05 PM.

Cause: Still unknown.

Third update:

9:30 PM (EST)

**x-number question with new activity** shows up with new questions that can be opened, but clicking on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?sort=newest&pageSize=50 or refreshing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php does not work.

Cause: Still unknown.

9:46 PM was asked to re-login and the problem persists.

If I am logged out, everything runs fine. All pages load, single or additional page tags, so this tells me it's an account-based problem.

- 4th update: **May 31, 2015 10:40 PM (EST).** Everything seems to be going OK for me now, yet I have not received/found any information nor an "answer" given for my question as to why this happened in the first place. This link given by a member in comments https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/604980738421866496 is the closest thing I can see on the subject.

Wednesday, June 3rd, 2015

- Still no answer as to why this happened and have not found anything while searching for it neither.

Comment: The pages with 2 tags loads for me in like 2 seconds and the single tag pages takes like 20 seconds, but they load for me. Really strange (Also like since this afternoon +/- (UTC+01:00))

Comment: [meta-tag:new-nav]? (I'm not part of the alpha at present and single-tag loads lickety-split first time every time.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy Not likely to be [tag:new-nav], all tag pages redirect to [a different url](https://stackoverflow.com/?show=all&sort=newest&layout=expanded&tagFilter=list&tags=php%20mysql) (which would most likely be linked).

Comment: @KevinBrown: Fair point. Timing made me suspicious, but you're probably right.

Comment: It currently works erratically for me, I never see an error page, but it is _sometimes_  slow, only for some tags though. [java] always seems fine though.

Comment: Slow for me as well. You notice on SO because of the sheer amount of questions but on MSE I see also some lag. Feels like a non-cached/recompile/missed index query or maybe the tag engine is slow

Comment: Pages with single tags don't work at first, then I tried loading that url, but with a + after it (so tagged 'php' and '{nothing}') and that worked but gave no results. Then I tried the single 'php' tag again and it worked instantly.The other singles then also worked...

Comment: Yeah. SO seems unusually slow today.  At times, I have to wait for over 10 seconds for questions to load. Saw the "Oops. This is our fault" page once because of this.

Comment: [Nick Craver is on the case](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/604980738421866496)